# Running Splunk equivalent of python scipy's code?

Tags: python, statistics, splunk

I am trying to define a splunk dashboard equivalent to this code in python

```
from scipy import stats
stats.beta.cdf(x, T, F) - stats.beta.cdf(y, T, F)
```

Where `x` and `y` are splunk expressions (defined with splunk's `eval`).

I saw a lot of complex stuff (classifiers, anomaly detection, etc...) when looking at the [splunk docs](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/MLApp/2.3.0/User/Algorithms), but I couldn't find any reference to known distribution functions such as [Beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) and [Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).

Could someone refer me to any statistics package for splunk ?

Comment: Take a look at their Machine Learning Toolkit's current list of algorithms http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/MLApp/latest/User/Algorithms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the `| script` directive in splunk.

Now, This is the python code I wrote, and it runs directly from splunk

```
from scipy import stats
import splunk.Intersplunk
src_cols = ["s1","s2"]
new_cols = ["n1"]
print (",".join(src_cols+new_cols))
for row in splunk.Intersplunk.readResults():
    output = map(lambda c: row[c], src_cols)
    output += [stats.beta.cdf(row["s1"],0, 1) - row["s2"],0, 1)]
    print (",".join(output))
```